# jquery post not working with HTML form

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am a beginner in Ajax and trying to build a simple ajax sample with jquery.
For some reason, my $.post is not working if I am putting my submit button in form tag.
Here is my creat_user.php:

```
<?php
$user_login = $_REQUEST['login_name'];
echo $user_login;
?>
```

Here is my html:

```
<form id='create_user_form'>
    <p><label>Login Name : </label><input type='text' name = 'login_name'></p>
    <p><label>Password : </label><input type='password' name='login_pw'></p>
    <p><label>Re-Enter Password : </label><input type='password' name='login_pw2'></p>
    <p><label>Email : </label><input type='email' name='email'></label></p>
    <p><label>Date of Birth : </label><input type='date' name='date'></p>
    <p><input type='submit' name='submit' id='create' value='create'></p>  
</form>
```

And jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#create_user_form").submit(function(){
        var serialize = $(this).serialize();
        alert('Here');
        $.post("create_user.php",serialize,function(response){
            alert('Here2');
            alert(response);
            console.log("Response: "+response);
       });
   });
});
```

For some reason, the alert('Here2') is never fired, but it will work if I move the submit button out from the form tag, it works.(I do changed the selector in jquery code and changed submit() to click() ):

```
<form id='create_user_form'>
    <p><label>Login Name : </label><input type='text' name = 'login_name'></p>
    <p><label>Password : </label><input type='password' name='login_pw'></p>
    <p><label>Re-Enter Password : </label><input type='password' name='login_pw2'></p>
    <p><label>Email : </label><input type='email' name='email'></label></p>
    <p><label>Date of Birth : </label><input type='date' name='date'></p>         
</form>
    <p><input type='submit' name='submit' id='create' value='create'></p>
```

SO, is that anything wrong from my code makes .post() not working if I put the submit button into form tag?

Comment: Is the page refreshing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `return false` or `preventDefault()` in the submit handler:

```
$("#create_user_form").submit(function(){
    ...
    return false;
});
```

Or

```
$("#create_user_form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

This will prevent the browser from submitting the form after the ajax request is sent.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need add

```
 return false;
```

at the submit event?

Answer (score 0):

The default form submit is occurring prior to the `Ajax` call returning.  You should prevent the default action of the form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#create_user_form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //do not submit the form.
        var serialize = $(this).serialize();
        alert('Here');
        $.post("create_user.php",serialize,function(response){
            alert('Here2');
            alert(response);
            console.log("Response: "+response);
       });
   });
});
```